# Como fazer com que uma operação execute momentos depois de eu ter clicado num botão?

Tags: java, android

Criei um app android simples que inicia uma service logo quando faço click num botão que eu mesmo coloquei, basta clicar no botão que ele inicia a service imediatamente.

O que eu quero agora é que ao clicar no botão a service demore algum tempo para iniciar. como posso fazer isso??

Aqui tem o código que lança o serviço:

```
public class NotifyService extends Service {

    private HandlerThread handlerThread;
    private Handler handler;
    private boolean started = false;

    //Define o tempo entre notificações, altere como quiser
    private final int TEMPO_ENTRE_NOTIFICAÇOES_SEGUNDOS = 7;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d("NotifyService", "onCreate");

        handlerThread = new HandlerThread("HandlerThread");
        handlerThread.start();
        handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Log.d("NotifyService","onStart");

        if(!started) {
            Log.d("NotifyService","Notificações iniciadas");
            started = true;
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    sendNotification();
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000 * TEMPO_ENTRE_NOTIFICAÇOES_SEGUNDOS);
                }
            };
            handler.post(runnable);
        }
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("NotifyService","Notificações terminadas");
        handlerThread.quit();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private void sendNotification(){
        Intent intent = new Intent (this ,
               Bca.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity
                (this, 0, intent, 0);
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder (this)
                .setContentTitle("Qsmobile")
                .setContentText("Consulte a sua fila")

                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.bcno)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .getNotification();
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService (NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify (0, notification);
        Log.d("NotifyService", "notificação enviada");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit após edição da pergunta.**

Se o que pretende é a primeira notificação ser feita com um *delay* igual às seguintes substitua

```
 handler.post(runnable);
```

por

```
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000 * TEMPO_ENTRE_NOTIFICAÇOES_SEGUNDOS);
```

Ficará assim:

```
if(!started) {
    Log.d("NotifyService","Notificações iniciadas");
    started = true;
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            sendNotification();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000 * TEMPO_ENTRE_NOTIFICAÇOES_SEGUNDOS);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000 * TEMPO_ENTRE_NOTIFICAÇOES_SEGUNDOS);
}
```

---

**Resposta original.**

Se for para executar na mesma Thread

- use um Handler:

  ```
  final Handler handler = new Handler();
  handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
          lancarServico();
      }
  }, 5 * 1000); // O método é lançado após 5 segundos.
  ```

Se for para executar em outra Thread

- use um HandlerThread:

  ```
  HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("HandlerThread");
  handlerThread.start();
  Handler handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());

  handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
          lancarServico();
      }
  }, 5 * 1000); // O método é lançado após 5 segundos.
  ```
- ou use Timer e TimerTask

  ```
  Timer timer = new Timer();
  TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
      public void run() {
         lancarServico();
      }
  };
  timer.schedule(timerTask, 5 * 1000); // O método é lançado após 5 segundos.
  ```

Criar uma nova Thread tem custos, neste seu caso o uso do Handler é preferível, já que lançar um serviço é uma operação rápida.

Comment: Era mesmo isso que eu queria.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa colocá-lo dentro de um Run, definindo o tempo de espera.

Por exemplo:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {       
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {       
                    //Inicia aqui o service depois de 5 segundos
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 5000); //execute in every 5000 ms
```

Comment: Não tem muita lógica criar uma Thread nova para depois executar o código na Thread original(aquela onde o Handler foi criado).